# Graphics#drawText, old text does not get erased

Tags: java, swing, paint

I have a JPanel which overrides paintComponent like this

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);    
    //[...]
    g.drawString(" x " + model.getCount(l), getTilesWidth() + ship.getWidth() + PREVIEW_OFFSET_X + 5, y - 10);
    //[...]
}
```

but when I call repaint and model.getCount(l) has changed, the new string gets just drawn above the old string. However, when I resize the window everything is fine again. What could be the cause for this?

Comment: -1, Not nearly enough information for us to make a reasonable guess. Based on the 2 lines of code you posted, your panel should repaint() properly. Therefore, the problem is with the code you didn't post. Don't keep us guessing. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to fill in the area where the old text was with the background color before attempting to draw the new text.

Comment: A JPanel is responsible for painting its own background. Invoking  super.paintComponent() makes sure this is done. The only reason this would work is if the poster has played with the opacity of the panel.

Answer (score 0):

ooops, the error was actually elsewhere, I really forgot that my class had a superclass other than JPanel, sorry for that.

Comment: And that is why a SSCCE should be posted with every question. It eliminates silly mistakes so we can spend our time on real problems.